# Generate Executable Jar for a Scala Project

Tags: scala, sbt, executable-jar

I have a scala project which contain multiple main methods. I want to generate a fat jar so that I can run one of the main method related code.

build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  organization := "my.company",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
  test in assembly := {}
)

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("my.test.Category")
  )
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

By this Manifest file is generated successfully in my resource folder.

next I run **sbt assembly** and executable jar is generated successfully.

When i run java -jar category-assembly-0.1.jar i get the following error

> no main manifest attribute, in category-assembly-0.1.jar

I tried many steps given in the internet but i keep getting this error

**UPDATE**

Currently following is included in my build.sbt.

```
lazy val spark: Project = project
  .in(file("./spark"))
  .settings(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("my.test.Category"),
      mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("my.test.Category"),
    mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("my.test.Category")
  )
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

After building the artifacts and run the command sbt assembly and tried running the genrated jar im still getting the same error as follows

> no main manifest attribute, in category-assembly-0.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was deploying on EMR.

Add the following to your setting in build.sbt and it will be alright.

```scala
lazy val spark: Project = project
  .in(file("./spark"))
  .settings(
     ...

     // set the main class for packaging the main jar
     mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.orgname.name.ClassName"),
     mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.orgname.name.ClassName"),
     ...

  )
```

This essentially sets the name of your existing class in your project as default mainClass. i set both for packageBin and run so you should be alright.

Just don't forget to rename the `com.orgname.name.ClassName` to your classname.

**(This is just to refresh your memory)**

Classname consists of `<PackageName>/<ClassName>`.

For example:

```scala
package com.orgname.name

object ClassName {}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @tharindu sorry for late reply. i recently switch to bazel for my scala build. i ran into this issue again but my solution for fixing it was to first check the jar file with `jar tf <jar file>` to see if my class name exists and then instead of using class name like `com.orgname.name.ClassName` i used the same path that i found from jar tf <jar file> minus the .class at the end. for mine looked like `com/orgname/name/ClassName`. give it a try maybe it solves your issue on sbt too